# Is it a good practice to call vars or methods with "this" inside the component template?

Tags: angular, typescript

I realize "this" refer to the instance method.

Calling variables and methods with "this" can get the same results as without one.

**Sample template (sample.html):**

```
<p> {{ this.getName() }} </p>
```

**Sample component (sample.component.ts):**

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'sample.html'
})

export class SampleComponent {

   public name: string;

   constructor() {
      this.name = 'John'; 
   }

   getName():string {
     return this.name;
   }
}
```

Based on the above codes,

both `{{ this.getName() }}` and `{{ getName() }}` can display the `John`.

Should I add "this" for a good coding style?

Or any concerns not to do it (eg, performance)?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I add "this" for a good coding style?

`this` is not conventional in angular templates. Use `{{ getName() }}`

## More

See the official tutorial for conventions : https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick answer, I previously checked https://angular.io/guide/styleguide but no references.

How can I tell if the code style is conventional or not.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is allowed in Angular template DSL to refer to component instance. `{{ this.getName() }}` and `{{ getName() }}` are identical.

`this` is supposed to specify property names with bracket notation.

Dynamically:

```
{{ this[methodName]() }}
```

Or statically:

```
{{ this['foo bar'] }}
```

It serves no good purpose to use `this` for component property names that can be specified with dot notation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are many use of "this", not just for good coding style.  And as you mentioned, "this" refer to the instance method.  Which means it is used to refer to a variable and/or parameter, for the system to know if the variable/parameter is being used for a certain line of code (but for this part this is mostly used in C#/Java).

Ex:

```
public class NewClass
{
   private string test;
    public string Test
    {
     get{return test;}
     set{test = value;}
    }
   //constructor with 1 parameter
   //which is also applied in angular but in different syntaxes
   //which you can see in Angular 5 which is made easier and cleaner
   public NewClass(string test) 
   {
        this.test = test;
   }
   public void SomeFunction(string test)
   {
     //the left side is the variable class test
     //while the right side is the parameter test
     this.test = test;
   }
}
```

In Angular the constructor I was refering to is something like this:

```
export class someClassComponent{
    constructor(private router : Router){
    }
    someFunction(var router){
       //left side is the router from the constructor
       //right side is the parameter
       this.router = router;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your explanation. Yes, I understand "this" is a must in some languages. However, with my learning in Angular, I found most codes, including official tutorial, directly calling the methods and variables instead of "this". Thus, a bit confused.

Comment: well for that case.. there are proprietary Framework which are made specific for the company which will might have global/public function/property with same name as yours inside an instance.  and "this" will make your function/property to be used in that case. and if you remove "this" the function/property from the framework will be called/used.

Comment: in angular, try creating a public function in a singleton, and try creating a function in a component, then try calling it in the developer console inside the instance of the component, you will know the difference.